# Annihilation and chemical energy

Tags: antimatter

We have two atoms of hydrogen, one atom of oxygen, and their antimatter counterparts. Now consider the following cases:

1. We let the hydrogen and oxygen react to obtain a molecule of water and thermal energy. We do the same with the antimatter. Then we let the molecules of water and antiwater meet and annihilate.
2. We skip the chemical reaction and annihilate the aforementioned atoms.

What happens to the "unredeemed" thermal energy in the second case? How is it released?

Comment: The total energy of annihilation in 1 will be less than the total annihilation energy in 2 by the amount of the thermal energy released in the chemical reaction.  Energy is always conserved (at least whenever GR is not involved).

Comment: @LewisMiller How will it be manifested? With extra photons produced or higher energy photons?

Comment: Probably same number of photons with slightly higher energy. Probably the difference will be too small to measure.